# Is it possible to keep only one desktop active at a time in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I would like to know if it is possible to keep only one Desktop active at a time ? I mean I know how to have multiple desktops, but they still all active at the same time, I would like something like 'put to sleep' all the inactive desktops ?
Thank you !

Comment: What do you mean be putting to sleep? The applications are open or not open, the OS is not like a mobile OS where off screen apps are turned or or put to sleep. Please more clearly explain what you want.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking  Windows virtual desktops are really nothing like the multiple desktop Linux/Unix has.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and I apologize for my ambiguous question, What I meants is like I have multiple use for my laptop (devleopping, studying X, studying Y...) each require different softwares and web pages, and achieving what I want through Windows 10 multiple desktops will mean that all these softwares and pages will always stay open.